# How can I email a flash animation (ecard) in an email body - not as an attached?

Tags: asp.net, web

We are creating a egreeting site using .net and are stuck in attaching flash image to the email body.I most of the flash ecard sites i gone through have given the link to the browser and from the browser flash image is viewed.Is there any method to show flash animation in email body?

Comment: I think E-mail clients will not render flash (.swf), even if embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Most populate email clients don't support embedded SWF in emails (for many good reasons). In addition, it just increases the likelihood of your email being designated as SPAM. To be honest, even getting legit HTML in anything but simple layouts to display well cross-email client is tricky enough task without trying to do what you're asking.

If you really want animations in an email, go with an animated GIF which links out to a URL that has the SWF in it. But of course, now you face the fact that most mobile devices do not support SWF either ;-)